# Normal distribution find the standard deviation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

The heights of school desks have a normal distribution with mean $69$ cm and standard deviation $\sigma$ cm. It is known that $15.5$% of these desks have a height greater than $70$ cm.

$i)$ Find the value of $\sigma$.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need to add the self study tag.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. You need to know how many desks there are in total. Then you could form and solve a equation. e.g. $P(H > 70) = p$ where $H \tilde{} N(69,\sigma^2)$ You currently have two unknowns. If you knew the total number of desks, it would help.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, can you help me now you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start you off, but being a maths teacher, can't bring myself to do it all :-)

The desk heights are normally distributed:
$H \tilde{} N(69,\sigma^2)$

The probability of a desk having a height more than 70cm is 15.5%:
 $P(H > 70) = 0.155$

The first step is to nomalize:

$P(H > 70) = 0.155$

$P(Z > \frac{70-69}{\sigma}) = 0.155$

Now you need to find your table of normal probabilities. At which point you discover you are only given values for $P(Z < z)$ for $z > 0$

So sketch a normal curve, shade in what you have and try and get it in the right form to lookup the value in your table.

Here's a flow diagram I give my students

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how to do the reverse lookup, I have that $P(Z > \frac {70 -69} {\sigma})$, how do I get z?

Comment: Next step, find $P(Z <\frac{70-69}{\sigma})$ you should then be able to find the probability in a table (use closest value) and corresponding z value